# FireBase Firestore retrieve multiple documents by list of ID's

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've got two collections for example `Cities` and `Houses`. Houses are not a nested collection of Cities, but a house contains a reference to a City.

Wat is the most efficient way to get city information for each house in a list?

For Example

```
class City {
  var name: String = ""
  var property1: String = ""
  var property2: String = ""
}

class House {
  var cityId: String = ""
  var propertyA: String = ""
  var propertyB: String = ""
}
```

I've got a list of houses, how do I get for each house in this list the name of the city? Is this possible by query, or should I just get all the cities (or each one seperate) and map them in code.

The cities and houses are just an example, but simular to my real situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplest way that I can think of is to create a new property to each house object called `cityName`. So your database structure should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- houses (collection)
        |
        --- houseId (document)
              |
              --- propertyA: "Property A" (document propery)
              |
              --- propertyB: "Property B" (document propery)
              |
              --- cityName: "City Name"
```

> how do i get for each house in this list the name of the city?

Just query your `houses` collection and get the corresponding city name. In code, should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference ref = rootRef.collection("Posts").document("Post");
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String cityName = document.getString("cityName");
                Log.d("TAG", cityName);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

So there is no need to keep a reference of the city in order to display the city name.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but i can see it would work. However i kept my question open in hope of an better solution, because if i implement this solution i need to store data multiple times which isn't that bad for 1 property but what if i need a second or a 3rd property..

Comment: That's no problem at all even if you duplicate an entire object. Take a look at [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Still need to learn a lot about NoSQL databases

Answer (score 2):

You can use com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldPath. This is working for me in kotlin:

```
//friendsIDs is ArrayList<String>
    firestore!!.collection("users").whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), friendsIDs).get().addOnCompleteListener {usersDocs ->
        if (usersDocs.isSuccessful) {
            val result = usersDocs.result!!
            val docs = result.documents
            for (userDoc in docs) {
                val friendData = userDoc.data!!
                //...
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("FirestoreRequest", "Error getting documents.", usersDocs.exception)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Java, but with a few modifications it worked for me.

Comment: @AlaaM. It's kotlin

Comment: This has maximum of 10 elements, not useful

Answer (score 2):

For a web app (JS), this works:
`db.collection('myCollection').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", collectionIds).where('status', '==', 2)` where `collectionIds` is an array of Document IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get multiple documents by a list of IDs in Android.

```
//Get Firestore instance
FirebaseFirestore ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

List<String> ids;

//... Fill ids list with document ids

//Fire query
ref.collection("collection_name").whereIn(FieldPath.documentId(), ids).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```